# Syntax error in postgres sql insert statement

Tags: postgresql, insert

In postgres sql, I have this

```
INSERT INTO user (email, password)
values ('joe', 'test');
```

seems simple enough, but I get this

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO user (email, password)
                    ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 13
```

I have a table called `user`, but I don't understand what's going on.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: That's what happens when you name tables using reserved words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have a table called `user`, but I don't understand what's going on.

`user` is a `PostgreSQL` [**reserved key word**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html), try quoting the table name:

```
INSERT INTO "user" (email, password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error message once, it meant I was using the wrong quotes, I had it like this:

```
 INSERT INTO tableName (columns) VALUES (‘string’)
```

when it should be

```
 INSERT INTO tableName (columns) VALUES ('string')
```

Some kind of copy and paste fail.  FWIW.